# Kotlin - Not able to run a main program in a multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a sample program using IDEA 2019.3 for Kotlin multiplatform library.

[image]

Then following structure has created automatically.

[image]

Then I added  following main in the commonMian/kotlin/Sample/Sample.class. I can see a green run button near the main function but on clicking that it shows "nothing here".

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

[image]

I am trying Kotlin for the first time. Could someone please tell what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Issue is only with the classes in CommonMain. I added the same main func in JvmMain/kotlin/sample and it worked

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: I posted here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35799 but so far no one responded

Comment: i have an opposite issue. entry points in jvm don't work. while common code works just fine